# preg_split String into Array at First Non-Numeric Character

Tags: php, arrays, preg-split

I have a string with some numbers and text and I'm trying to split the string at the first non-numeric character.

For Example, I have a few strings like

```
$value = '150px';
$value = '50em';
$value = '25%';
```

I've been trying to split the string using preg_split and a little regex.

`$value_split = preg_split( '/[a-zA-Z]/' , $fd['yks-mc-form-padding'] );`

I'm able to get the first part of the string using `$value_split[0]`, for example I can store 150, or 50 or 25. I need to return the second part of the string as well (px, em or %).

How can I split the string using preg_split or something similar to return both parts of the array??

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use regex and you haven't already, you should play with [RegExr](http://www.regexr.com/).

To do what you're wanting with regex, assuming all the strings will be all numeric together, followed by all non-numeric, you could do:

```
$matches = array();
preg_match('/([0-9]+)([^0-9]+)/',$value,$matches);
```

Then `$matches[1]` will be the numeric part and `$matches[2]` will be the rest

To break it down,
`[0-9]` matches any numeric character, so `[0-9]+` matches 1 or more numeric characters in a row, so per [the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) `$matches[1]` will have the (numeric) text matched in by the first set of parentheses

and `[^0-9]` matches any non-numeric character, so `[^0-9]+` matches 1 or more non-numeric characters in a row and fills `$matches[2]` because it's in the 2nd set of parentheses

Comment: Wow, seems to work very well. I'll have a play around with it and see if it is consistent. Thanks Jakar, and thanks for the RegExr site resource, I hadn't seen that before!

Comment: You're welcome. As long as all of the `$value`s are numeric characters only, followed by non-numeric characters only (like 123a%b), then it will work 100% of the time.

Comment: good, but try using `\d` and `\D` instead of `[0-9]` and `[^0-9]`

Answer (score 3):

By `preg_split()` you cannot achieve what are you trying to. It will delete the part of your string which separates the whole string (in this case it will be separated by character `[a-zA-Z]`). Use `preg_match()` (or `preg_match_all()`) function.

You can use this pattern:

```
/([0-9]+)([a-zA-Z%]+)/
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/pP3kG6/3).

Comment: using `[^0-9]` for the 2nd match is more universal than `[a-zA-Z_%@#]` because it matches ANY non-numeric character instead of just the few specified. Given the use case, though, it probably won't matter either way.

Comment: I totally agree with you, but I don't want to look like I am copying you :). But for this case it is irrelevant due to he wanted 3 values probably for CSS which have 3 formats (px, em and %). So characters such as `_@#` are not important here. I will edit.

Answer (score 1):

Use the PREG_SPLIT_OFFSET_CAPTURE flag - it will cause an array to be returned, with item [0] being the string matched, and item [1] its starting position in the original string.
You can then use that info to extract the rest of the string by using ordinary sub-string functionality.
Something along the lines of:

```
$values_split = preg_split( '/[a-zA-Z]/' , $fd['yks-mc-form-padding'] );
$position = $values_split[0][1]
$length = $values_split[0][0]
$startPos = $position + $length
$numToGet = lenght($input) - $startPos

$remainder = substr($inline, startPos, $numToGet)
```